# When parameter name equals function name: who wins?

Tags: c, scoping

(I have this uneasy feeling that I've asked this before, but now I can't find it.  Feel free to close and redirect this question if so...)

In C, assume I have a function named `thing()` and some other function that uses `thing` as a  formal parameter:

```
thing_t *thing(int id) { ... function that returns a *thing_t ... }

void foo(thing_t *thing) { ... function that takes a *thing_t as an argument ... }
```

Inside the body of `foo()`, is there any guarantee that `thing` refers to the passed-in parameter as opposed to the function of the same name?  Do any of the C specifications have anything to say about this?

(And yes, I'd agree that this is dubious coding style...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the function `thing` declares `thing` as an identifier with *file scope*, per C 2018 6.2.1 4. Its scope extends from its declaration (specifically, from the end of its declarator, `*thing(int id)`) to the end of the translation unit.

The definition of the parameter `thing` in the definition of `foo` declares `thing` as an identifier with *block scope*, also per 6.2.1 4. Its scope extends from its declaration to the end of the block that is the body of the function definition.

Then the final sentences of 6.2.1 4 tells us that within `foo`, `thing` refers to the parameter, not the function:

> If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the *inner scope*) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity (the *outer scope*). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is *hidden* (and not visible) within the inner scope.

Answer (score 3):

Parameters to functions are at a more "inner" scope than file scope objects such as function names, so the parameter `thing` masks the function named `thing`.

This is spelled out in section 6.2.1p4 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) regarding the scope of identifiers:

> If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
> space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the
> inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity
> (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the identifier designates
> the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the
> outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**